# Записать строку вида 010.. в uint8_t формат

Tags: c, алгоритм

я разрабатываю программу которая получает на вход текст и обработав его алгоритмом шеннона-фано, сохраняет его в другой файл. Сейчас я на этапе когда у меня есть код вида 01... для каждого символа. Этот код является строкой, как мне преобразовать его в uint8_t такого же, чтобы записать в бинарный файл. Для того чтобы это действительно был алгоритм сжатия

Comment: Так обрабатывайте группы по 8 символов, побитово создавая uint_8. Можно `strtol` привлечь